# Hibernate Session.flush() efficiency problems

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, flush

Sorry in advance if someone has already answered this specific question but I have yet to find an answer to my problem so here goes.

I am working on an application (no I cannot give the code as it is for a job so I'm sorry about that one) which uses DAO's and Hibernate and POJO's and all that stuff for communicating and writing to the database.  This works well for the application assuming I don't have a ton of data to check when I call Session.flush().  That being said, there is a page where a user can add any number of items to a product and there is one particular case where there are something along the lines of 25 items.  Each item has about 8 fields a piece that are all stored in the database.  When I call the flush it does save everything to the database but it takes FOREVER to complete.  The three lines I am calling are:

```
merge(myObject);
Session.flush();
Session.refresh(myObject);
```

I have tried a number of different combinations of things to fix this problem and a number of different solutions so coming back and saying "Don't use flus()" isn't much help as the saveOrUpdate() and other hibernate sessions don't seem to work.  The only solution I can think of is to scrap the entire project (the code we got was inherited and poorly written to say the least) or tell the user community to suck it up.

It is my understanding from Hibernate API that if you want to write the data to the database it runs a check on every item, if there is a difference it creates a queue of update queries, then runs the queries.  It seems as though this data is being updated every time because the "DATE_CREATED" column in my database is different even if the other values are unchanged.

What I was wondering is if there was another way to prevent such a large committing of data or a way of excluding that particular column from the "check" hibernate does so I don't have to commit all 25 items if I only made a change to 1?

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: 25 isn't really that many, unless the objects are ginormous.  Anyway, is each item being handled in its own session, or are they all being added to the session before the flush?

Comment: Ok so turns out it is more like 60+ objects haha.  I don't remember this many but that's how many there are now.  Each item is being added to the same session though and I call flush at the end.  I tried making a dateCreated field in the POJO set to updatable=false as a way of ensuring the check doesn't happen on that field which is the problem but that didn't work.  Got any ideas?

Comment: you need to figure out what is taking the time.  Is is object manipulation, db inserting, whatever....

Comment: What's taking so long is the fact that the objects are all being checked against the db and since each one has a different time stamp than the last time it was modified, it is being flagged as needed to be updated.  I want to prevent this by happening by saying a difference is DATE_CREATED doesn't mean the data is dirty.  I just need to know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you really cannot avoid the dirty checking in hibernate unless you use a [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html). Of course, you lose a lot of features (lazy-load etc.) with that, but it's up to you to make this decision.

Another option: I would definitely try to use **dynamic-update=true** in your entity. Like:

```
@Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
class MyClass
```

Using that, Hibernate will update the modified columns only. In small tables, with few columns, it's not so effective, but in your case maybe it can help make the whole process faster as you cannot avoid dirty checking with a regular Hibernate Session. Updating a few columns instead of the whole object is always better, right?
[This post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/) talks more about dynamic-update attribute.

Comment: That sounds like it could at least put a dent in fixing the performance problems.  I will look into StatelessSession as well since I don't think lazy loading is something the users couldn't live without.  Thanks for the help.  If you think of anything else please post it.

Comment: Yeah. Take a look. About the StatelessSession, I didn't mean you have to use it everywhere. Just where you need to use a batch like in that case above. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What I was wondering is if there was another way to prevent such a
>   large committing of data or a way of excluding that particular column
>   from the "check" hibernate does so I don't have to commit all 25 items
>   if I only made a change to 1?

I would profile the application to ensure that the dirty checking on flush is actually the problem. If you find that this is indeed the case you can use evict to manage the session size.

```
session.update(myObject);
session.flush();
session.evict(myObject);
```